# Unit Test for the following with a Page returning list of Employees on the page

Tags: unit-testing

The page is showing the employee details in a table format Now I want to write a unit test for this view. Please help me to write the same

```
public ActionResult EmployeePage()
    {
        MVCTutorialsEntities db = new MVCTutorialsEntities();

        List<Employee> employeeList = db.Employees.ToList();

        //EmployeeView employeeVM = new EmployeeView();
        List<EmployeeView> empViewList = employeeList.Select(x => new EmployeeView
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Address = x.Address,
            DepartmentId = x.DepartmentId,
            DepartmentName = x.Department.DepartmentName
        }).ToList();

        return View(empViewList);
    }
```

Comment: Specify programming language. | Clarify, do you want to test a controller method or a view?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov This is ASP.NET MVC Project and a Controller Method with return view

Comment: Is it Java? Is it Python? Is it C++? Add tag please!

Comment: You wrote: "I want to write a unit test for this **view**". But you show us controller method, not view!